# Is it possible to amplify an AC low level signal with a simple DC source?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, dc, oscilloscope

The project has an input from -1V to +1V for input.  I need a linear 0 - 5Vpp output with the same wave frequency (60Hz).

I tried this (and other configurations), but never get the output I need.

I have project restrictions: I only have this power supply (5Vcc), so I can't use a -5 + 5 symetric voltage, or higher voltage.

The scope output seems to show a saturated output.

I'm thinking - after days searching, calculating and trying - that it might be impossible to have this, that's why I'm asking here.

I simplified the schematic to paste here (but added have some capacitors for decoupling only.)

I tried to add a DC stage to bring the signal to a 2.5V offset (doesn't work.)

Is it possible?  How can I make it work?

| Schematic | With "offset" |
| --- | --- |
| [image: schematic] | [image: with offset] |

**Scope output**

[image: scope output]

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried to correct  with the tips I got here and circuit runs better, but not yet in the correct way (I want re 'blue'(out) oscilates from 0V to 5V. Seems saturated yet on the top of  output curve.

✔ I got the right offset (2.5V).

✔ Got the 0V minimum

✖ Don't the 5V maximum

| schematic | osciloscope output |
| --- | --- |
| [image: circuit] | [image: scope] |

**UPDATE 2:**

I take a look at the software from uController I'm using to get the 5V variarion, and **if I get an output that is like a Diode cutted signal (half wave) but that have the maximum value in the output** (that could be the 5V), maybe I can use this signal.

Comment: Have you tried AC coupling and level shifting the input to the amplifier?

Comment: In addition to Aaron, R4 needs to connect to 2.5V, not ground because at zero AC input (or 2.5V at the opamp input after level shifting with a DC bias) you want an output of 2.5V, not 0V. Your gain is also too high. You're not looking at what the numbers actually are. You chose a gain of 5, but your PEAK is 1V which is only half the input dynamic range of the input signal (-1V to 1V) while your full dynamic output range is 0-5V.

Comment: Have you checked the datasheet for the LM358 to see if it can provide a rail-to-rail output voltage? You should also check for the acceptable range of input voltages.

Comment: @Aaron I though the 'offset I did could solve this, but seems its not.

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks for the tips. I changed the gain to 2.5 (2vpp to 5vpp) and connected R4 to 2.5V the osciloscope signal shows better.

Comment: @Elliot, Yes this is a problem in my circuit. I saw LM358 just manage levels from -0,3V up, so I need to adjust the input level.

Comment: The LM358 is a bad choice for this, it can't output voltages too close to the positive rail.

Comment: Your offset circuit is incorrect.  It needs to be AC coupled first.  Currently it's just an extra load on the source.

Comment: @Hearth do you have another option to suggest. The only I have here are 358 and 741 OPAmps

Comment: Think I correct this (at new answer)

Comment: Regarding your latest test (which I assume will be edited out of an answer and into the above question shortly) -- the LM358 can reliably swing from maybe 1V to 3V at the output with a 5V/0V supply and a relatively low value resistance from the output to a voltage above ground, so you can't really afford any gain and an offset of 2.0V is about right. You have a gain of +3, so it is saturating, and more so on the high side.

Comment: Why do you want 0-5Vpp output?

Comment: @HenriqueVilela - Hi, Your "answer" (which wasn't a full answer to your original question, and therefore should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box) has now been added to the question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. Unless you are writing the *full* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, you should edit the question to add new information, test results etc. (This is one way that Stack Exchange differs from forums. See the [tour] & [help] for more rules.)

Comment: The 741 is even worse than the 358. Neither of the op amps you suggest will work for the task you want.

Comment: Just to clarify, does the input signal go -1V to +1V pk to pk or 0V to +1V pk to pk as you say in the first line of your question?

Comment: @BruceAbbott to enter in a ADC of a microcontroller. I though about 'translate' the range I got to 0-5V via software, but i think I'll loss information doing this (using less bits to get the value).

Comment: @James -1V to 1V .. when I said 0-1V I mean the input range will vary from 0V to 0V to -1 V to +1V, the values may have a precision to  4.9mV between 0 to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a LM358 powered by a +5V supply, the output will saturate at a volt or two below +5V as you are seeing. You require a rail to rail output op amp, such as the MCP601, for the output to be able to reach very close to +5V when the power rail is +5V.

[image: Level shifter and amplifier]

With this circuit, any chosen rail to rail output op amp should also have a common mode input range that includes ground.

Comment: Maybe I will need to find this IC so. Thanks for clearifying!

Comment: I tried on my circuit and, only changing the IC (without any changes on circuit) I get the result! Thanks for you and for all that helped me!

Answer (score -1):

True rail-to-rail amplification is a difficult problem, but if the only issue is output voltage, and the signal is AC, a simple one-transistor buffer amplifier and a step-up output transformer is a good solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvkCQr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you get a transformer with a 1:10 windings ratio, you can
adjust the R1 and R2 values for the 'right' gain.   Output
can be made positive (connect 'bias' lead to +5V)
or ground-centered (connect 'bias' to GND),

Comment: I'm not familiar in 'making' transformers, but I'll search about. Seems even a less complicated solution (if I can have a correct transformer). I tried at first with transistors but having almost the same results that I had with the OPAmp but with more noise.